# How to fetch individual rows, that would have specific sums if be grouped

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, firebird, firebird2.5

The database I'm using is Firebird 2.5.

I want to select only the data that if I sum the column `money`, I get all the rows for all persons that summing their `money > 0`, and also it should contain the rows with `money = 0` if it exists for that person.

Example:

```
select name, surname, country, money from person group by 1,2,3 having sum(money)>0
```

It's giving me:

```
SQL Error [335544824] [42000]: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause) [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544824]
  Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause) [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544824]
    Dynamic SQL Error
      SQL error code = -104
      Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)
```

But if I add the `money` column to the group, it works, but it doesn't return the rows which contain `money = 0`:

```
select name, surname, country, money from person group by 1,2,3,4 having sum(money)>0
```

This is giving an error:

```
    SELECT stag, COMMESSA, MODELLO, linea, DATA_PROD, finiti
        FROM JAVA_PRODUTTIVITA 
    GROUP BY stag, commessa, MODELLO, linea, DATA_PROD 
    HAVING sum(finiti)>0;
```

but if I add in the group **finiti**:

```
    SELECT stag, COMMESSA, MODELLO, linea, DATA_PROD, finiti
        FROM JAVA_PRODUTTIVITA 
    GROUP BY stag, commessa, MODELLO, linea, DATA_PROD, finiti 
    HAVING sum(finiti)>0;
```

the result:

```
STAG |COMMESSA |MODELLO   |LINEA |DATA_PROD           |FINITI |
-----|---------|----------|------|--------------------|-------|
18S  |00254    |S3BS01W   |L1    |2018-01-12 00:00:00 |21     |
18S  |00254    |S3BS01W   |L1    |2018-01-15 00:00:00 |56     |
18S  |00254    |S3BS01W   |L1    |2018-01-16 00:00:00 |41     |
18S  |00254    |S3BS01W   |L2    |2018-01-18 00:00:00 |58     |
18S  |00254    |S3BS01W   |L2    |2018-01-19 00:00:00 |44     |
18S  |00254    |S3BS01W   |L2    |2018-01-24 00:00:00 |16     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L1    |2018-01-09 00:00:00 |54     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L1    |2018-01-10 00:00:00 |56     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L1    |2018-01-11 00:00:00 |60     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L1    |2018-01-12 00:00:00 |40     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L1    |2018-01-17 00:00:00 |15     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-10 00:00:00 |70     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-11 00:00:00 |80     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-12 00:00:00 |90     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-15 00:00:00 |100    |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-16 00:00:00 |70     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-17 00:00:00 |33     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-18 00:00:00 |19     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-19 00:00:00 |23     |
18S  |00255    |S3BS01X   |L2    |2018-01-23 00:00:00 |5      |
18S  |00306    |MPLR16W   |L1    |2018-02-07 00:00:00 |20     |
18S  |00306    |MPLR16W   |L1    |2018-02-08 00:00:00 |47     |
18S  |00306    |MPLR16W   |L1    |2018-02-09 00:00:00 |58     |
18S  |00306    |MPLR16W   |L1    |2018-02-12 00:00:00 |96     |
18S  |00306    |MPLR16W   |L1    |2018-02-13 00:00:00 |86     |
18S  |00306    |MPLR16W   |L1    |2018-02-14 00:00:00 |32     |
18S  |00307    |MPLR16W-  |L1    |2018-02-21 00:00:00 |112    |
18S  |00307    |MPLR16W-  |L1    |2018-02-22 00:00:00 |86     |
18S  |00307    |MPLR16W-  |L1    |2018-02-23 00:00:00 |118    |
18S  |00307    |MPLR16W-  |L1    |2018-02-26 00:00:00 |102    |
18S  |00308    |MPLR16X   |L1    |2018-02-27 00:00:00 |40     |
```

and somewhere between the lines should be a record with `finiti = 0`, but it is not.

Comment: Please show an example with data and expected results for that data.

Comment: What you added now seems to be an actual result, I asked for sample data and **expected** result for that data, so we can try to glean the logic of what you want to do. I would strongly suggest that you create sample data specifically for this question, and limit it to a small number of rows.

Comment: because, that is not how aggregate functions work - they do not give you individual rows, they give you aggregate results by all rows taken together. So you have to use a secondary query to select the specific rows, that were combined into the aggregate result of the first query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your sample SQL, the following SQL might work.

You didn't specify a key, so I used all fields in your group by for the inner join.

```
WITH SUMMARY
AS (SELECT NAME,
           SURNAME,
           COUNTRY
    FROM PERSON
    GROUP BY 1,
        2,
        3
    HAVING SUM(MONEY) > 0)
SELECT PERSON.NAME,
       PERSON.SURNAME,
       PERSON.COUNTRY,
       PERSON.MONEY
FROM SUMMARY
INNER JOIN PERSON ON (PERSON.NAME = SUMMARY.NAME AND PERSON.SURNAME = SUMMARY.SURNAME AND PERSON.COUNTRY = SUMMARY.COUNTRY) ;
```